# QT SFML Integration Trouble

Tags: c++, 2d, sfml, qt

I have been having trouble linking sfml to qt creator I have downloaded the pre-compiled libraries and headers for MINGW on the sfml website here : http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3.2/

This is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SFML_MapEditor
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\VsIncludes\SFML\SFML-2.3.2\include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:\VsIncludes\SFML\SFML-2.3.2\include"

LIBS += -LC:\VsIncludes\SFML\SFML_QT\SFMLLIBS\

CONFIG(debug, release|debug): LIBS += -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-main-d -lsfml-system-d -lsfml-network-d
CONFIG(release, release|debug): LIBS += -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-main -lsfml-system -lsfml-network
```

Here is the project files where the binaries are read

[image: The executable files]

Now my problem lies in the loadFromFile() function.
When I do run the program with the loadFromFile() function
it will immediately give me this error:

C:\Users\Alex\Documents\QT_Projects\SFML_MapEditor\main.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_4RectIiEE'

However when I run the program without loadFromFile()
it will run without a hitch

My main.cpp file

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <QDebug>

void SFML_Test()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "HELLO SFML");

    sf::Texture tex;

    if (!tex.loadFromFile("Default_Texture.png"))
    {
        return;
    }

    sf::Sprite sprite(tex);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;

        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
    */

    SFML_Test();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have done further testing and it is only the loadFromFile function that will create this error in both the image class and texture class

Comment: I fixed my .pro file however I still get the undefined function reference from loadFromFile

Comment: Another thing, I have built the libraries with my version of mingw

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I was using sfml 2.3.2 which I guess isn't fully compatible with qt creator so I tried sfml 2.0 and it suddenly worked.

Here is a link to a video describing how to link SFML to Qt Creator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWvD4mUpyfU